# Method not found: Void Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.PowerBIClient..ctor - Power BI Embedded

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, powerbi

I have a problem with Power BI Embedded.
I want to embed a power BI report in a partial view.
Following the guide, I created these methods on my controller:

```
public ActionResult Report()
    {
        credential = new UserCredential(username, passwordPowerBI);
        Authorize().Wait();

        ReportEmbed myReport = new ReportEmbed();

        using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(apiUrl), tokenCredentials))
        {
            EmbedToken embedToken = client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroup(groupId, reportID, new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "View"));
            Report report = client.Reports.GetReportInGroup(groupId, reportID);

            myReport.reportID = reportID;
            myReport.embedURL = report.EmbedUrl;
            myReport.embedToken = embedToken.Token;
        }
        return PartialView(myReport);
    }

    private static Task Authorize()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () => {
            authenticationResult = null;
            tokenCredentials = null;
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

            authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, clientID, credential);

            if (authenticationResult != null)
            {
                tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");
            }
        });
    }
```

And in the view I just try to view my report.
But the application go to this exception:

[image]

(sorry, some text is in italian. "Impossibile trovare il metodo" means "Method not found").

What is the problem? Something is missing in the web.config?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a version mismatch with the assemblies. Compile time it finds the correct assembly, while run time it loads an older version of the client. Check your deployment and make sure you are using the correct assemblies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How check correctly this? I simply get the nuget Power BI package and add it to my solution. Nothing else.

Comment: Check the path from which you are referencing the assembly. Most likely you get this as NuGet package, so it should be in your solution's folder. Check what is deployed - look in your binaries folder, check is there anything installed in the GAC. It's hard to say anything more specific, but in general search for files with the same name, but different versions.